# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' when I want to import sparkdl in databricks

Tags: databricks

I am trying to implement a deep learning pipeline, I need to import sparkdl package in databricks (community edition).
My other installed libraries include:

`spark-deep-learning:1.4.0-spark2.4-s_2.11`,
`h5py`,
`keras==2.2.4`,
`tensorflow==1.15.0`,
`wrapt`.

When I run

`from sparkdl import DeepImageFeaturizer`

I keep getting the error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`.

**Update: Installing `Pillow` solves the problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed all the libraries as the prerequisites:

- Create a spark-deep-learning library with the Source option Maven and
  Coordinate `1.4.0-spark2.4-s_2.11`.
- Create libraries with the Source
  option PyPI and Package `tensorflow==1.12.0`,`keras==2.2.4`, `h5py==2.7.0`,
  `wrapt`.

**Reference:** https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/deep-learning/deep-learning-pipelines-1.4.0.html

Comment: My problem is that I did not install `Pillow` library.

Comment: Glad to know your issue had resolved. Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: same problem for `from sparkdl import DeepImagePredictor`. I installed `Pillow` to my cluster and it is working now. Thanks guys :)